# Is drinking water while standing haram?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

What does Islam say about drinking water while standing? Is it haram or simply not liked ?

Answer (score 3):

Prophet Muhammad SAW forbade us from drinking and eating while standing. This [hadith](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/3/44) makes it clear:

> Anas (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>   The Prophet (ﷺ) forbade us from drinking while standing. Qatadah reported: "We asked him: 'What about eating?"' He said: "That is even worse, (or may be he said) more detestable."

[Islamqa.info](http://islamqa.info/en/21147) elaborates it and says that

> The scholars reconciled these hadeeth by stating that the forbidding mentioned here does not mean that it is haram, rather it is to be understood as advice, and that it is better to drink whilst sitting.

And it [turns out](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_is_it_not_advisable_to_drink_water_while_standing?#slide=5) that drinking water while standing causes GERD (gastroesophageal reflux disease).

So, it is not haram, but harmful.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not Haram.

It is Mustahab (recommended) to drink water while sitting during nighttime and while standing at daytime.

Imam Sadiq a.s. said:

> Drinking water while standing at nighttime causes bile in body.
>   (reference of hadith: [Man la yahduruhu al-Faqih](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_la_yahduruhu_al-Faqih), vol.3 page 353)

Imam Sadiq a.s. said:

> Drinking water at daytime while standing causes more sweating and
>   makes the power of body more. (reference of hadith: [Man la yahduruhu
>   al-Faqih](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_la_yahduruhu_al-Faqih), vol.3 page 353)

Imam Sadiq a.s. said:

> Drinking water while standing at daytime makes the food digestible and
>   tasty and drinking water while standing at nighttime causes bile (reference of
>   hadith: [Kitab al-Kafi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitab_al-Kafi), vol.6 page 383)

---

**Referenecs:**

- [food & drink -Permitted & Prohibited](http://islamic-laws.com/fooddrinks.htm)
- [www.islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa3050)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not haram at all. But it's well known that the prophet (PBUH) used to drink while sitting.

> Al-Bukhaari (1637) and Muslim (2027) narrated that Ibn Mas’ood (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: I brought water to the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) from Zamzam and he drank whilst standing.

For more information about this, you can visit this page also:
http://islamqa.info/en/21147

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research there are slightly contradictory hadith regarding this:

> Narrated An-Nazzal: Ali came to the gate of the courtyard (of the
>   Mosque) and drank (water) while he was standing and said, "Some people
>   dislike to drink while standing, but I saw the Prophet (ﷺ) doing
>   (drinking water) as you have seen me doing now." - [Sahih al-Bukhari: USC-MSA web (English) reference : Vol. 7, Book 69, Hadith 519](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/74/41).

.

> Anas reported Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) disapproved the drinking of water
>   while standing. - [Sahih Muslim: USC-MSA web (English) reference : Book 23, Hadith 5017](https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/148).

Use these information for your decision or try some additional research and update us if you find a definite ans.

Also have a look [here](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=drinking%20water%20standing).